# How to detect what changed in array in Ember.js?

Tags: arrays, ember.js, momentjs

I'm on Ember 2.12.

I have an array `selectedDays: [Object]` in the controller that is passed to component. component has an array like `monthDays: [Object]`. Objects in component need to have `selected` property set if they can be found in the array from controller.

The problem is comparing objects is very costly, based on Moment library method (`moment1.isSame(moment2, 'day')`). So right now when I add something to `selectedDays` array, every object in `monthDays` needs to be compared with every object in `selectedDays`. This can be hundreds or thousands of costly comparisons.

The `monthDays` always have 42 length (6 weeks) but `selectedDays` can be tens or hundreds.

I wonder is it possible to optimize that without some bruteforce custom sorting/finding optimization.

The simplest solution would be: on controller array change, check what exactly changed and modify only one day that matches the change. But as far as I know:

- you can't send an action from controller to component
- array observers don't "know" what exactly changed in array (?)

What other options do I have?

I set up an Ember Twiddle where there's visible 200-300ms delay every time you click a day before it becomes selected.

Comment: Can you store only the indices of data in selectedDays array? Or can you wrap your days as `{day, isSelected}`?

Comment: I can wrap my days, in fact they are wrapper, but that doesn't change the fact I don't want to modify the objects in controller (DDAU). `selectedDays` are raw `moment()` objects, they are not stored in app Store.

Answer (score 0):

When you change selectedDays in controller, do you know `object` that you are going to add/remove? if its so then you can pass that newlyAddedDays object to component, and in component `didUpdateAttrs` hook, you can check with newlyAddedDays and set the `selected` property in component.

```
{{my-component selectedDays=selectedDays newlyAddedDays=newlyAddedDays }}
```

Initially `newlyAddedDays` will be empty/undefined.

my-component.js file,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        //prepare selected property using the selectedDays from controller and monthdDays in component.
    },
    //this hook will not be called for first render.
    //It will be called whenever you change selectedDays/newlyAddedDays. ie, whenever the passed property is updated 
    didUpdateAttrs() {        
        if (Ember.isPresent(this.get('newlyAddedDays'))) {
            //look for it and update selected property.
        }
    }

});
```

From your options,

> you can't send an action from controller to component

Don't do this. instead, you can try with service having the modified property and component will take it from there.

> array observers don't "know" what exactly changed in array

Yes. Array observers don't know what exactly changed, so you have to write the code for taking the diff.

Comment: Not a perfectly clean solution, but makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Ya I know it's not perfect solution, but I would love to know does this solved delay you are facing right now.

Comment: I actually asked this question months ago. : )